# Files in /var are gone

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, apt

I have mounted an additional hard drive and all my files in `/var` are gone.

I added one more [EBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store) hard drive in [Amazon EC2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud). After mounting that drive my whole `/var` is gone.

I cannot even start Apache and also cannot use `apt-get`...

What should I do to restore it to be like before or at least make `apt-get` working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like a) you accidentally mounted var to your EBS volume. Something like this:

```
mount /somevolume /var
```

you'll need to this:

```
umount /var
```

Or it is b) you accidentally unmounted var. Quickest way is to remount all (hopefully var still exists in fstab:

```
mount -a
```

We definitely need the steps you have done, but at this point, you really have nothing else to do short of trying to rebuild /var.

Comment: I guess that worked. :}

Comment: It helped me to get the idea :)

Answer (score 7):

You need to hire someone who knows about Unix & Linux to manage your server.

We can only help so much - there is a minimum level of understanding necessary that you do not appear to have.

Comment: +1 - You appear to be in ***way*** over your head -- Seek. Professional. Assistance. Preferably before you do irreparable harm to your environment.

Answer (score 5):

Did you mount your new volume over the top of your existing /var ? If you unmount your new 'hard drive' does it reappear ?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: It appears but apache does not work like before and what should I do to mount that extra drive and make everything works fine?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Successfully adding one more hard drive to my EC2 instance(Increasing my storage capability) and keeping everything else same.

Comment: @Jeong, you have to be really specific as to what you're trying to achieve. It's pretty obvious you want to add more storage...

Comment: Okay. I'm running mongodb, apache and php with mod_php.
I want to make them work fine just as before but still want to add a hard drive.

Comment: @Jeong - You can't even describe the issue in a meaningful way. You really should hire someone that knows what they are doing.

Comment: I acknowledge that I'm a novice on serverfault issues. I will just try and learn from scratch.